# Is that a pure mind stone on top of Wanda's vision?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

I'm talking about the show [WandaVision](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt09140560/).

**Spoilers ahead**....

We get to know that Vision living with Wanda is actually created by Wanda herself. She was in grief and that caused uncontrolled power surge which created the new Vision. What about the mind stone! Is it a real mind stone? In episode 9, Vision told old Vision that his mind stone has not an ounce of material from the real stone. Then, is it a replica? Is it actually powerful similar to actual mind stone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about the soul stone! Is it a real soul stone?

> In episode 9, Vision told old Vision that his soul stone has not an ounce of material from the real stone.

To start with, it's not the Soul Stone that was in Vision it was the **Mind Stone**.

### As for whether the replacement "stone" was real, then NO!.

The Westview Vision was a completely magically created entity that was brought into existence by Wanda's memory.

> You, Vision... are the piece of the Mind Stone that lives in me. You are a body of wires and blood and bone that I created. You are my sadness and my hope. But mostly, you're my love.
>
> Read more at: https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=879&t=42946

Comment: Oops! My bad! I actually meant mind stone. But made a blunder. Edited the question now. But the question remains - "Can new-mind-stone mimic the same power as the earlier one if someone took out of new-Vision's head within the Wanda zone?" Is Wanda that much powerful!!

Comment: That's pure speculation and we have no way of knowing. What Wanda can do now is completely up for grabs until we see her again in the MCU.

Comment: The extent of the powers of new-Vision's "Mind Stone" are the powers that he displays. Which so far seemed identical; he could bring individual people out of the hex (and return them to hit), phase through objects, fire the yellow beam, etc. Of course, we don't even fully know what the Mind Stone is capable of in the first place.